# Collision, hood unlatches and disconnects from the holder that locks it in place but won’t open & gets caught on something while lifting it up

Tags: malibu, hood

It’s a 2006 Chevy Malibu. I was in a collision the other day and there was a lot of damage to the front of the vehicle. I am trying to get into the engine compartment to assess the damage (I know at least the radiator needs to be replaced) but whenever I try to open the hood it won’t work. The release mechanism from the driver seat works just fine, and then whenever I reach my hand in the hood and unlatch the lever it disconnects but then catches on something about a quarter of the way from lifting it. I have stuck my phone under and looked while lifting it but don’t see any visual obstruction.

Comment: Look where the hood meets the body just in front of the windshield. It could be binding there.